# How to get a multiple-line input from a user in Java and then store the input in an array of type string where every line is an element of the array

Tags: java

For example,
input:

```
Name Alex
Age 25
Nationality Sweden
Spoken Languages Swedish and English
```

output:

```java
["Name Alex", "Age 25", "Nationality Sweden", "Spoken Languages Swedish and English"]
```

Comment: Just use a BufferedReader or Scanner. It would be best to store the strings in an ArrayList<String> rather than an array. Just use a while-list to input each line of text until the stream is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Scanner class you can take input from cmd and store each line into Array of String or In ArrayList collection.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        in.add(line);

        if (line != null && line.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
            System.out.println("Output list : " + in);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```